# Hibernate unsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I use `Spring+maven+Hibernate Spatial`. I need to download table from `MySql` database. I created whole application and while running I am getting this:

```
Hibernate: select geopoint0_.point as col_0_0_ from geo_point geopoint0_
2013-06-28 11:39:31.549:WARN::/Sample/companies
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.hibernate.spatial.GeometrySqlTypeDescriptor.getExtractor(GeometrySqlTypeDescriptor.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(QueryLoader.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:639)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2542)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at b2b.lol.dao.GeoPointDAOImpl.findByCompany(GeoPointDAOImpl.java:27)
    at b2b.lol.service.GeoPointServiceImpl.listGeoPoint(GeoPointServiceImpl.java:18)
    at b2b.lol.controller.HomeController.companies(HomeController.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:401)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I use **Hibernate** `-core 3.6.9`, **mysql connector** `5.1.10` and **hibernate spatial** `4.0-M1` 
Thanks for any advice.

EDIT: This exception causes query.list(); from this(point type is POINT):

```
public List<?> findByCompany(long companyId) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Query query = session.createQuery("select  point from GeoPoint");

    List<?> rows = query.list(); 
        return rows;
```

Comment: can you show the code which is causing this exception?

Comment: Post your hibernate query here? Try to debug your code

Comment: query problem in ur hibernate

Comment: My code is shown in edited post

Answer (score 0):

The query looks strange for an hql query, try:

Select p from GeoPoint p

Answer (score 0):

From the Hibernate spatial web site I see the following:

> Hibernate Spatial version 4.0 is compatible with Hibernate 4.x

But you say you are using Hibernate core 3.6.9. Maybe you need to upgrade your Hibernate version?